# How to centralize the QTreeWidget header

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

How to centralize the `QTreeWidget` header?

I have the following `QTreeWidget`:

[image]

And I want to centralize the header to look like this:

[image]

I already tried to set this stylesheet:

```
QHeaderView::section {
     text-align: center;
 }
```

But it didn't work.

I know that with `QTableWidget` we can do something like this:

```
myTableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(0)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

But `QTreeWidget` doesn't have horizontalHeaderItem().

I'm on Qt 5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
ui->myTreeWidget->header()->setDefaultAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

Set the default alignment as centralized to the `QHeaderView`.

Documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#defaultAlignment-prop